# 質問が自己解決できた場合

Tags: サポート, 質問の仕方, 回答の仕方

Stack Overflowで質問した内容が自己解決できてしまった場合はどうすればいいのでしょうか?
自分の質問に自分で回答して、回答済みにするのも、おかしいような気がします。
いったいどうすべきなのでしょうか?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stack Overflowがいいリソースになるためには、回答があることが大事です。誰も回答しないのより、自分で回答したほうがいいと思います。

例えば、こちらは私が初めて投稿した質問ですが、自分で回答しました:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062952/retain-formatting-using-group-by-aggregation-in-google-visualization-api

質問した時点では回答がわかる人がいなかったため、結局自分で回答してしまいました。最近、投稿から2年以上たってから同じ問題にぶつかった人が回答を追加しました。自分で回答するのはあまりと思っていても、2年後その回答を見つけた人が喜ぶこともあるかもしれません。