# 質問を自分から終了したい場合には?

Tags: 討議, サポート

作成した質問を、諸々の理由により自分から終了したくなりました。どのような手段が取れるでしょうか?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 手段1: 自己回答する

質問を自分で解決できた場合には、自身で回答を投稿する「自己回答」を行うことが推奨されます。 詳細は次をご覧ください。参考: [質問が自己解決できた場合](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1747/754)

#### 手段2: 質問を削除する

サイトに対して価値を付与しない質問・回答投稿は、質問者自身ないしコミュニティメンバーによって削除されていくことが推奨されます。特定の条件を満たす質問投稿は、削除することが可能です。対象投稿の下部に表示されている「削除」リンクから実行できます。削除の実装詳細については次をご覧ください。参考: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions

ただし注意として、その投稿が本当にサイトにとって不要でないかぎり、質問の削除(とくに回答がよせられている場合) は好まれません。 参考スレッド: [回答が寄せられた後に質問を削除し、少し内容を変えて再投稿するのはあり？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2094/754)

#### 手段3: 質問とアカウントを切り離す

自己回答できず、削除できない質問投稿があった場合、それは放っておくのが基本ではありますが、例えば当該の質問にマイナス投票が重なっているような場合において、かつその質問の編集による改善が難しい場合、その質問を放置するしかないのは望ましくありません。

[No way to delete an answered question @ meta.stachexchange に寄せられた回答](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86618/301070) によると、「質問を匿名化する」というオペレーションが、可能な様子です。これにより、その質問とアカウントを切り離すことができる様子です。このオペレーションはまだこのサイトで実際に実行したことはないと思うので、詳細までは分かりませんが。。この手段を行いたい場合は、「その他」の通報により、モデレーターに「質問を匿名化したい」ことをお伝えください。