# 不要になった質問は、コミュニティとしてどう取り扱われるべき?

Tags: 討議

このメタ投稿を作成しているのは、今まさに具体例があるからで、それはこれです。 [Pythonで日本語を正規表現によってtxtファイルから助詞等を除きたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/41095/754)

---

たとえば、質問の前提が変わるなどして、投稿していた質問を終了したくなる場合があります。そして、それが実際に投稿者によって明示されている質問があるとします。さらに、特にこの質問に対する回答は寄せられていないとします。

このような場合、コミュニティとして、この質問はどう取り扱われるべきでしょうか? というのも、質問者の立場として、取れる行動は、次のメタポストで記述した通りです。 [質問を自分から終了したい場合には?](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2634/754) しかしこれは、質問者に対する選択肢であって、このような質問を見かけた場合のコミュニティ(メンバー)としての選択肢ではないです。

またこの投稿の前提として、「回答を求めていない質問」はどうにか整理した方が良い、という認識があります。例えば、回答を求めていない質問が大量にある Q&A サイトというのは、あまり良い状態ではないと思うからです。

---

コミュニティとして取れる選択肢としては、以下があると思います。

- 放っておく
- upvote/downvote する
- クローズする (その他理由のクローズで、例えば、「前提が変わって回答が必要とされていない」とするなど)

  - そして削除する (クローズ後2日が経過している質問に対しては削除投票が行えます: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions )
- その他?

---

#### まとめると

- 質問者によって「この質問は前提が変わるなどして回答をこれ以上必要としない」とされた質問に対して、コミュニティとしてこれはどう取り扱われていくべきでしょうか?

Comment: 最終的には削除されるべきだと思いますが、回答を必要としないとされてから削除するまでの過程で、同じような質問が生まれないよう次につながる効果が欲しいですね（特に同じ質問者からは）

Comment: 回答がついていない前提があるのであれば、クローズ後、削除に1票。ですが、同じような質問を封じるまでは必要ないと考えています。